# translation for "It serves as a good reminder for me"?

Tags: usage, translation, set-phrases, phrase-requests

After I've say watched a film with some friends (or read a fable or something) and learned something from it, i want to say `"It [the teachings of this fable/film] serves as a good reminder for me"`. I'm wondering is there a phrase in japanese which conveys this meaning?

If not could I say this: `僕にとって良いリマインダとして提供してる。`?

Or will it sound awkward (like a non-native speaker)?

If so what are the alternatives?

Comment: See this question in meta: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76/should-pure-translation-questions-be-allowed  The consensus seems to be that this is not the place for pure translation questions unless they involve the finer points of the language.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Amanda S: It's a general english expression to japanese. Where in meta does it say that this question should be closed. The most upvoted votes show that this question should not be closed. In what is it different from http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/818/does-the-usa-english-idiom-unable-to-see-the-forest-for-the-trees-keep-its-me ?

Comment: @Pacerier: Try to use 目的にかなう or 事足る or 役立つ in your sentence. You can try and search for a japanese word for reminder otherwise the katakana version is リマインダー

Comment: @rep The question you cited is about whether an idiom keeps its idiomatic meaning when translated into Japanese, hence it is more than just a pure translation question.  If Pacerier had a particular question about some nuance of the translation (like [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/800/it-system-renewal-can-i-say-for-renewal) asks), that would be more acceptable.

Comment: Oh, so it's possible to hide a pure translation question behind some clever words ;)

Comment: The only thing I can think of for a good translation of this would be 銘記と（なる／なった）もの

Comment: @repecmps guys i've edited the question. pls reopen it thx

Comment: @Amanda S and girls

Comment: The question looks good to me, but I'm just an average user, I cannot help with administrative things...

Comment: Only people with 500 reputation or more can vote to close/reopen questions. I think you'll just have to wait, Pacerier. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions

Comment: I still think that this is a question about pure translation, but I am happy to be convinced otherwise.  If anyone has an opinion about it, please [post on meta](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/176/scope-translation-for-it-serves-as-a-good-reminder-for-me).

Comment: @repecmps . heys you could help reopen the question here http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/176/scope-translation-for-it-serves-as-a-good-reminder-for-me

Comment: @rcjsuen heys you can help reopen it here: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/176/scope-translation-for-it-serves-as-a-good-reminder-for-me

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito btw i've edited it again

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a phrase request. It is undeniably a translation question, but it is also a genuine appeal for help to express something in another language. (The English stackexchange site has a phrase-request tag, maybe we should have one too?)

Comment: I say close this question! This is a symbolic opportunity for the topic police to strike a victorious blow, sending a stern message to the electronic world about what is appropriate. How dare someone ask translate-phrase-to-Japanese question in a Japanese language Q&A site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it might sound awkward to a native-speaker, I think the point you are making would still make its way across languages.  But, as a nit-picking aside, how would something be a *reminder* if it is something you *just* learned? :)

Although it's not the explicit meaning you are wanting to use here, it may be more natural to (instead) use a phrase like: `あの映画には感動したよ.私に大切なことを考えさせてくれました.`  But it's up to you; one of the best ways to find out the "awkwardness factor" is to try using your phrase and seeing how the listener responds. :)

Comment: Nice suggestion lol, thanks for the help =)

Comment: Maybe certain teachings are supposed to be a part of a properly developed human being. And if such an expectation exists, then it is indeed a reminder to conform to such expectations.

Comment: @Flaw That makes sense; might have to do with the topic of morality, then.

Comment: Here it seems like 'reminder' is meant in the sense of 'admonition' or 'warning', almost.　勉強になった、感銘を受けた。On the other hand,戒め might be a little strong.